# Get The Items Under An Expanded Node in AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, advanceddatagrid

Is there a way to get the items which are under an expanded ADG tree node?

Given the sample tree node:

```
- Atlantic
    Celtics
    Nets
    Knicks
    Sixers
    Raptors
+ Central
+ SouthEast
+ SouthWest
+ NorthWest
+ Pacific
```

I am planning to capture the data in the ADG's itemOpen event.

```
private function myADG_ItemOpen(event:AdvancedDataGridEvent) :void
{
  // What codes do I put here to get the following teams:
  // Celtics, Nets, Knicks, Sixers, Raptors
}
```

Update:
I managed to pull off some codes that somehow provides me an object containing the teams:

```
var ihd:IHierarchicalData = IHierarchicalCollectionView(myADG.dataProvider).source;

    if(ihd.hasChildren(evt.item))
    {
      var objGetChildren:Object = ihd.getChildren(evt.item);
      var dataString:String = ObjectUtil.toString(objGetChildren);

      // From here, I am able to parse the dataString to an array, where I am able to get the team name.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the ADG from the `AdvancedDataGridEvent` and then you can try to cast its `dataProvider` to an `IHierarchicalCollectionView`. If that worked you can use it to get the children of the opend node.

```
private function myADG_ItemOpen(event:AdvancedDataGridEvent):void
{
    var grid:AdvancedDataGrid = AdvancedDataGrid(event.currentTarget);
    var dataProvider:IHierarchicalCollectionView = grid.dataProvider as IHierarchicalCollectionView;

    if (dataProvider && event.item)
    {
        var children:ICollectionView = dataProvider.getChildren(event.item);

        if (children)
        {
            // do something with the children
        }
    }
}
```